# python3 win32serviceutil Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion"

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I use `win32serviceutil` from `pywin32` to create win service using `python3.6.4` and i can not run it from services because of this error :

```
PS C:\pytest> net start MyService2
The service is not responding to the control function.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.

PS C:\pytest> net helpmsg 2186

The service is not responding to the control function.    

Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion" when attempting to start, stop or pause a service

PS C:\pytest> python.exe .\winservice.py restart
Restarting service MyService2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\winservice.py", line 86, in <module>
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 609, in HandleCommandLine
    RestartService(serviceName, args[1:])
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 434, in RestartService
    StartService(serviceName, args, machine)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 417, in StartService
    win32service.StartService(hs, args)
pywintypes.error: (1053, 'StartService', 'The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashio
n.')
```

I tested code on `windows server 2012 r2` and `windows 10` and `windows 7` and always go this error .

This is my code :

```
import win32serviceutil  
import win32service  
import win32event  
import servicemanager  
import socket  
import configparser  
import os  
import inspect  
import logging  
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):  
    _svc_name_ = "MyService2"
    _svc_display_name_ = "My Service2"

    _config = configparser.ConfigParser()

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        self._config.read(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) + '/config.ini')
        print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))))
        print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) + '/teconfig.ini')

        print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))))  
        print(self._config.sections())

        logDir = "C:\\pytest"
        logPath = logDir + "/service-log.log"

        self._logger = logging.getLogger("MyService2")
        self._logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler = RotatingFileHandler(logPath, maxBytes=4096, backupCount=10)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self._logger.addHandler(handler)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))

        self._logger.info("Service Is Starting")

        self.main()

    def main(self):
        # your code could go here
        rc = None
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:

            print(1)
            # mycode ...

            # hang for 1 minute or until service is stopped - whichever comes first
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, (1 * 60 * 1000))

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

and this is windows event log :

```
PythonService.exe 
   3.6.223.0 
   5a924bf0 
   pywintypes36.dll 
   6.3.9600.18821 
   59ba8666 
   c0000135 
   0009d4c2 
   1c30 
   01d3be7d982684d6 
   C:\Python\lib\site-packages\win32\PythonService.exe 
   pywintypes36.dll 
   d5d346d8-2a70-11e8-8137-74d4352a14b5
```

another windows event log:

```
   APPCRASH 
   Not available 
   0 
   PythonService.exe 
   3.6.223.0 
   5a924bf0 
   pywintypes36.dll 
   6.3.9600.18821 
   59ba8666 
   c0000135 
   0009d4c2      
   0 
   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_PythonService.ex_a6d37d2a67edc3482c57ce89bdf2468d8fdb_1e95645b_114f887d 
   d5d346d8-2a70-11e8-8137-74d4352a14b5 
   4100
```

and this is my system path :

```
C:\Users\dvp7>echo %PATH%
C:\Python\DLLs\;C:\Python\Scripts\;C:\Python\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32
\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\;C:\Program Files\python35\Scripts\
;C:\Program Files\python35\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\syste
m32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1
.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program
Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8
.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\
Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Users\dvp7\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Use
rs\dvp7\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I use this [article](https://blog.bensoer.com/create-windows-service-in-python-3/) to create this code.
interested thing is service run in `debug` mode from powershell.